# Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ail

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, psql

I'm trying to install `psql` on Mac (M1). I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/how-to-install-psql-on-mac-ubuntu-debian-windows/).

I'm in this step: `brew link --force libpq ail`, but I get the error `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ail`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Might be a typo. Try running `brew link --force libpq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a typo. I tried the commented suggestion `brew link --force libpq` and it worked.